# Solution Space of $ax + by = 0$

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm a student taking a Linear Algebra course for the first time and came across this problem: 
In this problem we continue the Geometry Problem from Chapter 2, but now we work in three-space.

Considering the infinite linear system given by the equations $\ ax + by = 0$ where you should think of these as having a $z$ variable with a zero coefficient, describe the solution space of the system.

For reference, the question from Chapter 2 refers to:

An infinite system of linear equations in two variables given by $ax + by = 0 $ where $(a, b)$ moves along the unit circle in the plane. Recall that the vector $(a, b)$ is the normal to the line with equation $ax + by = 0 $ 
although I'm not entirely sure whether this is the same situation for the question I'm working on now.

The answer key states that the solution space is the $z$-axis; however, I'm entirely confused as to how this was determined.

For one, doesn't the zero coefficient make the equation exist solely on the z-plane?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you familiar with three-dimensional vectors? For example: do you know that two vectors are orthogonal iff their dot product equals zero?

Comment: @Pacciu I am familiar with 3D vectors and the dot product, however, we aren't utilizing those concepts for this assignment.

Answer (score 3):

Because of the zero coefficient on $z$ you can consider the solution in the $xy$ plane, then just extend everything in $z$ because nothing changes when you move in that direction.  In the $xy$ plane the solution is a line through the origin with slope $-\frac ab$.  In $\Bbb R^3$ the solution is a plane perpendicular to the $xy$ plane and intersecting it in the line $ax+by=0$.